# Yarn -v is giving out this error that I couldn't understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, yarnpkg, macos-mojave

I'm having a problem setting up a rails dev environment on my Macbook Pro. I've developed Rails (4.0-5.0) before and has since been focusing on another framework (MERN, Jekyll, etc.). I decided to come back to rails to create a small app.

So I would `gem install rails` (using Rails 6.0), and it would show succeed but warned me of some error.

The errors I would get related to webpack.yml and yarn.

I google everywhere and StackOverflow everywhere.

After my research, it was suggested that I fix webpack.yml by creating webpack.yml in config/ (don't know why it wasn't created when use `rails new myapp`). Problem solved....now on to yarn problem.

so I did this:

```
➜ myapp git:(master) ✗ yarn -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/johntowery/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/bin/yarn:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/johntowery/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/johntowery/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem yarn (>= 0.a) with executable yarn (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Why is `yarn -v` causing this error?  When I set up rails dev environment, I get all sort of erros and almost half of them related to `yarn`.

I was able to start rails using `bundle exec rails server`, and I was able to go to http://localhost:3000, and it displays "Yay! You're on Rails" as expected.

BUT... I need to fix this `yarn` issue. I need to fix it now, so I don't have to deal with it later on.

Any feedback/answer/suggestion will be appreciated.

thanks.

#### updates:

I did try to create another app with `rails new myapp2 --webpack`. This is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/johntowery/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/bin/yarn:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/johntowery/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:480:in `block in replace_bin_path'
/Users/johntowery/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:460:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable yarn for gem yarn. yarn is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
```

#### Additional Info

yarn is already installed via homebrew and other method. still no help

Answer (score 0):

In case your ruby v2.6.0 you should be upgrade rails 6 with webpacker as default
[rails 6 release](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v6.0.0) and [how to upgrade](https://medium.com/@prrrnd/upgrading-to-rails-6-and-getting-started-with-action-text-7f50aafc8631)

Hope useful for you

Comment: Yes I did use Rails 6 with webpacker. (I had to edit my questions because it seems I used the rough draft not the final draft).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installs `yarn` in your Macbook

try `brew install yarn`

Comment: yarn is installed .  tried the homebrew, gem, etc etc . nothing seems to help

Comment: Maybe the path is wrong. Use `echo $PATH` to see the path config, if you don't see the `/usr/local/bin`, add the `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` to `.zshrc` and restart your terminal
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#understanding-path